# How do I add a header, video, and footer with minimum page size?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a header and footer with a video that fills the middle content area while maintaining the aspect ratio. Furthermore, I would like to have a minimum page size. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qMwLHG?p=preview) is what I have so far. My current problem is that when I hit the minimum page size the the header and footer move over the video. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h2>
        Header
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <video  class="video" controls>
        <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <h2>
        Footer
      </h2>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.body {
    min-width: 640px;
    min-height: 480px;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width:  100%;
    min-width: 640px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #dedede;
}

.content{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px; /*header height*/
    bottom: 70px; /*footer height*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-width: 640px;
    min-height: 360px; /*480 - header & footer*/
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 640px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    text-align: center;
}

.video{
    height: 100% !important;
    width: auto   !important;
    max-width: 100%    !important;
}
```

Comment: please note the pages take a second to load

Comment: i think i deserve an upvote... i put time and effort into that answer

Answer (score 0):

adjust your footer so that it sticks to the bottom of the page. Adjust it to position:relative and set a then create a div called push and set it to a height of 70px(same as your footer)
Put the div id ="push" in between the content and the footer.

then, set a margin-bottom of 70px on your content.

Done!

Updated code:

```css
.body {
  min-width: 640px;
  min-height: 480px;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 640px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dedede;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
  min-width: 640px;
  min-height: 360px;
  /*480 - header & footer*/
}
.push {
  height: 70px;
  clear: both;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 640px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>
        Header
      </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <video class="video" controls>
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>
        Footer
      </h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: set all your divs to relative

Comment: if you want to divide the content from the header you can add margin-top of 10px or so

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up resolving it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="body">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <video class="video" controls>
        <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        I am sorry, your video failed to load.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.body{
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 480px;
  min-width: 640px;
}

.header{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer{
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
}

.video{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```